# Como puedo parar de leer con next()

Tags: java

El ejercicio es el siguiente:
Dado un texto organizado por líneas, el problema de las referencias cruzadas consiste en producir un listado de palabras ordenado alfabéticamente, donde cada palabra del texto va acompañada de una lista de referencias que contiene los números de todas las líneas del texto en las que aparece la palabra en cuestión, ordenados de menor a mayor.

Entrada:
La entrada consta de diversos casos de prueba. Cada caso comienza con el número N de lineas que forman el texto (entre 1 y 10.000).
A continuación, aparecen N lineas con las palabras (entre 1 y 30)
del texto, donde se han omitido los signos de puntuación o tildes.  Las palabras tienen como mucho 10 letras.
La entrada termina cuando N es 0.

Salida:
Para cada caso de prueba se escribirán las referencias cruzadas, donde solamente se tendrían en cuenta palabras con más de 2 letras y no se tendrían en cuenta las mayúsculas.
En las listas de números de linea no habría repeticiones (aunque la palabra aparezca varias veces en la misma linea). Tras procesar cada
caso se escribirá una línea más con ----.

Entrada de ejemplo:
4
Guerra tenia una parra y Parra tenia una perra
la perra de Parra rompio la parra de Guerra y Guerra aporreo con la porra a la perra
Si la perra de Parra no hubiera roto la parra de Guerra
este no hubiera aporreado con la porra a la perra de Parra
0

Salida de ejemplo:
aporreado 4
aporreo 2
con 2 4
este 4
guerra 1 2 3
hubiera 3 4
parra 1 2 3 4
perra 1 2 3 4
porra 2 4
rompio 2
roto 3
tenia 1
una 1

Lo podéis encontrar de todas maneras en acepta el reto, el desafío 291.
La pregunta es que al hacerlo me da un error y es que no puedo parar de leer el string de palabras ni con hasNext() ni nada, alguien tiene la solución?.
Este es mi codigo:

```
public class Desafio_291 {
    private Map<String,Integer>mapaPalabras;

    public Desafio_291() {
        this.mapaPalabras = new TreeMap<>();
    }
    

    private void introducePalabra(String palabra){
        if(mapaPalabras.containsKey(palabra.toLowerCase())){
            for(String p: mapaPalabras.keySet()){
                if(p.equalsIgnoreCase(palabra))
                    mapaPalabras.put(p, mapaPalabras.get(p)+1);
            }
        }else
            mapaPalabras.put(palabra.toLowerCase(), 1);
    }
    
    private void printMap(){
        for(String p: mapaPalabras.keySet()){
            System.out.println(p + "->" + mapaPalabras.get(p));
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Desafio_291 d = new Desafio_291();
        int numLineas;
        String palabra;
        
        do{
            numLineas = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            if(numLineas==0)
                break;
            
            for(int i=0; i<numLineas; i++){
                palabra = sc.next();
            }
            d.printMap();
        }while(numLineas!=0);        
    }    
}
```

PD(He solucionado el ejercicio con un arraylist pero sigo queriendo saber si se puede hacer con un solo string que lea con next() ya que de esta forma haría más rápida y sencilla la lectura de las palabras, sin tener una lista)
La solución con arraylist es muy sencilla:

```
public class Desafio_291 {
private Map<String,Integer>mapaPalabras;
ArrayList<String>palabras;

public Desafio_291() {
    this.mapaPalabras = new TreeMap<>();
    this.palabras = new ArrayList<>();
}

private void ingresaFraseArray(String frase){
    int inicioPalabra = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<frase.length(); i++){
        if(frase.charAt(i)==' '){
            palabras.add(frase.substring(inicioPalabra,i));
            inicioPalabra = i+1;
        }
    }
}

private void introducePalabra(String palabra){
    if(mapaPalabras.containsKey(palabra.toLowerCase())){
        for(String p: mapaPalabras.keySet()){
            if(p.equalsIgnoreCase(palabra))
                mapaPalabras.put(p, mapaPalabras.get(p)+1);
        }
    }else
        mapaPalabras.put(palabra.toLowerCase(), 1);
}

void printMap(){
    for(String p: mapaPalabras.keySet()){
        System.out.println(p + "->" + mapaPalabras.get(p));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Desafio_291 d = new Desafio_291();
    int numLineas;
    
    do{
        numLineas = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        
        
        if(numLineas==0)
            break;
        
        for(int i=0; i<numLineas; i++){
            d.ingresaFraseArray(sc.nextLine());
            for (String palabra : d.palabras) {
                d.introducePalabra(palabra);
            }
        }
        d.printMap();
        d.mapaPalabras.clear();
    }while(numLineas!=0);
    
}
```

}

Comment: Hola Jorge, primero debes sacar **numLineas = sc.nextInt();** del `do-while`, luego en el `for` agregas **numLineas--;** :)

Comment: No es eso lo que quiero, eso haría que después de cada palabra bajara en 1 el numero de líneas, y yo no quiero que baje con cada palabra, quiero que baje con cada frase. Y que después de introducir todas las frases me responda con la salida que he puesto en el enunciado. Es decir clave(palabra) -> valor(veces que se repite la palabra en el mapa).                                               PD: Lo he sacado con un ArrayList, además del mapa lógicamente, pero me gustaría saber si se puede hacer de la forma que antes he mencionado, con un solo string que lea con next().

Comment: En el ejercicio se parte de la idea de que tienes una cadena separada en lineas, con lo deberías usar un String como dato, pero tal vez no es lo que quieres hacer, deberías explicar en que te quieres desviar de la consigna.

Comment: La cadena puede variar y ser cualquier cosa que introduzca el usuario. Viene en el enunciado, léelo.

Comment: Si, pero es **una** cadena.

Comment: no, ya que tiene espacios, son varias cadenas y de cada cadena quiero coger cada palabra e ingresarla en el mapa.

Comment: La primera frase dice: **Dado un texto organizado por líneas**, es verdad que no es concluyente, y tu interpretación puede ser correcta, lo que si está claro, es que no es mediante el ingreso "a pulso" de las cadenas, ya que el ejercicio  tiene que tardar menos de 4 segundos (al menos yo lo interpreto así).

Comment: Es parte del Scanner bloquear la entrada. Aquí tienes una alternativa https://stackoverflow.com/a/4983156/13419694

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> clave = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Integer>> filas = new ArrayList<>();

void run() {
  long numero1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
  String cadenas[] = texto.split( "\n" );

    // le dí a i un valor 1, y a la condición cadenas.length - 1, porque
    // en el enunciado, el texto de prueba empieza con una linea que 
    // contiene un "4", y termina con otra que contienen un "0", no hay a
    // quien preguntarle si realmente son del texto a procesar, si no te
    // parece correcto, usa los valores nominales.
  for( int i = 1; i < cadenas.length - 1; i++ ) {
     String cadi[] = cadenas[ i ].split( " " );
     for( int k = 0; k < cadi.length; k++ ) {
        if( cadi[ k ].length() < 3 ) {  // descarta palabras de dos letras.
           continue;
        }
        String palabra = cadi[ k ].toLowerCase();
        if( !clave.contains( palabra ) ) {
           List<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();
           num.add( i );
           filas.add( num );
           clave.add( palabra );
        }
        else {
           for( int j = 0; j < clave.size(); j++ ) {
              if( palabra.equals( clave.get( j ) )) {
                 if( !filas.get( j ).contains( i ) ) {
                    filas.get( j ).add( i );
                 }                  
              }                  
           }
        }
     }
  }
  for( int i = 0; i < clave.size(); i++ ) {
     for( int j = 0; j < clave.size() -1; j++ ) {
        if( clave.get( j ).compareTo( clave.get( j + 1 ) ) > 0 ) {
           String aux = clave.get( j );
           List<Integer> numAuxA = filas.get( j );
           String auxA = clave.get( j );
           clave.add( j, clave.get( j + 1 ) );
           clave.remove( j + 1 );
           clave.remove( j + 1 );
           clave.add( j + 1, auxA );
           filas.add( j, filas.get( j + 1 ) );
           filas.remove( j + 1 );
           filas.remove( j + 1 );
           filas.add( j + 1, numAuxA );
        }
     }
  }
  for( int i = 0; i < clave.size(); i++ ) {
     System.out.println( clave.get( i ) + " "+ filas.get( i ) );
     
  }
  
  long numero2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
  System.out.println( "tiempo = " + ( numero2 - numero1 ) );
}
```

El enfoque que usé, es raro, en vez de usar un `Map` (que me complicaba a la hora de ordenarlo), uso dos `List`, uno de `String` que funciona como `key`, y el otro de `List` de `Integer`, donde acumulo los valores.
A medida que va iterando, si no tiene la `key`, la carga en clave, crea un nuevo `List` al que le agrega **`i`** (el número de fila), y agrega este a **`filas`**.
Si tiene la `key`, busca su posición, verifica que en esa posición, pero de **`filas`**, no este el valor de **`i`**, en cuyo caso lo agrega.
Lo que sigue, es ordenar los dos `List`, es la porción de código que se lleva más tiempo ejecutar, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo de otra manera, simplemente aplico el algoritmo de la burbuja, en paralelo a ambos `List`, osea, uso a **`clave`** como guía, y hago los mismos movimientos en **`filas`**.